# Manifest Merger Failed issue in React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest

I am trying to run the React Native Application on my Android device but i am getting an error says "Manifest merger failed" , i have tried a lot to solve the issue but i am not getting any working solution please have a look on the attached Screenshot and suggest a solution , Thanks.

[image]

Comment: In your project directory, Navigate to android\app\src\main. Edit AndroidManifest.xml and add `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"` in the application tag. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @RaviKumar i tried it  , but it does not work.

Comment: Send more info and delete the node modual and install again.